# MySql Replace and update column contents with regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using user defined regular expression from this [blog](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

Example Column Statement: [userid:30] is an user.[editor:67] is an administrator.

I need to replace [userid:30] and [editor:67] in above statement with empty. What is the regular expression to match this? I've used with this pattern  **[[^]]+]** but this not works well

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a "regex replace" function.  This is a pain to do in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`^Column Statement: (\[userid:[0-9]+\]) is an user.(\[editor:[0-9]+\]) is an administrator.`

Now $1 & $2 will be [userid:30] and [editor:67]. This is because they are wrapped in brackets.

Use a editor like sublime that highlights matching text as you type. Make it much easier to learn regex.

Comment: Thanks For ur reply. I've tested with above patterns like this **select regex_replace('\[userid:[0-9]+\]','','i am the [user_id:39]');** But tat not works

Comment: Try  select regex_replace( '.*(\[userid:[0-9]+\]).*(\[editor:[0-9]+\])' , 'I am the user $1' );